# AAPT: error: '0' is incompatible with attribute layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf (attr) reference|enum [parent=0]

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, build.gradle

I was doing the layout and when starting the emulator I got this error
I tried to clean the code and rebuild it also I already reinstalled the android studio.
Also I tried "Invalidate Caches" but the problem still exists

I read on the medium that you need to remove 'kotlin-parcelize'

but still it didn't work for me, can someone help me. i have seen im in medium that's I supposed to put , what I should to do?

This is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eef4fb"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lottie" />

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/lottie"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the Java file

```
package com.allforus.bookclub;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;

@SuppressLint("CustomSplashScreen")
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_main);
    }
}
```

This is the build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.allforus.bookclub"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.8.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in  the xml file in bolow properties , use parent instead of 0

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="0"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="0"

app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="0"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="0"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="0"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="0"
```

Comment: Like @rahulk pointed, need to use parent instead of 0. The only place I could see "0" is in the generated APK file. No where its documented to use 0. So the "0" value comes mostly comes from obfuscated code and the equivalent is to use "parent".